# Enforce reveal effect in UWP XAML

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I defined a toolbar for my UWP app like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ToggleButton Margin="5,5,0,5" Height="40" Width="30" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonRevealStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets " Content="&#xF156;"/>
                <ToggleButton Margin="0,5,5,5" Height="40" Width="30" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonRevealStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets " Content="&#xE8FD;"/>

                <Button Margin="5,5,0,5" Height="40" Width="30" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets " Content="&#xE70D;"/>
                <Button Margin="0,5,5,5" Height="40" Width="30" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets " Content="&#xE70E;"/>
                <TextBox Margin="5" TextAlignment="Center" Height="40" Width="1" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent" Padding="7" FontSize="16"/>
                <Button Margin="5,5,0,5" Height="40" Width="30" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets " Content="&#xE8A3;"/>
                <Button Margin="0,5,5,5" Height="40" Width="30" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets " Content="&#xE71F;"/>

                <Button Margin="5" Height="40" Width="40" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets " Content="&#xE7AD;"/>
                <Button Margin="5" Height="40" Width="40" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets " Content="&#xE799;"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

This is the (correct) result:

[image]

But sometimes the reveal effect is just not shown:

[image]

Why is this the case? How can I enforce the reveal effect at all times?

Comment: What's your reveal style look like?

Comment: It's actually the [built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/reveal#enabling-reveal-on-other-controls) one.

Comment: Ah right, that light bulb didn't go off immediately. Try adding a 1px margin between same type button sets and if still same issue use `Grid` instead of `StackPanel` and apply sizes to it instead with same 1px between controls (I know, sounds odd, but try it) because it should be a persistent effect but it's also depending on a measure/arrange pass.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. unfortunately it doesn't work. After some investigation I found that this might be a focus issue: I use a a ScrollViewer and after interacting with it sometimes (but not always) the reveal effect does not work until I click into the title bar. But still no clue why this happens.

Comment: Ah yea the ScrollViewer would be fighting for events, that makes sense. Unfortunately I don't know a trick for that for this instance off the top of my head. Cheers though

Comment: I noticed that too. Seems like a bug to me. When reveal effect doesn't work, send your mouse pointer all the way towards taskbar, and then bring it back, it should work then 